# In ASP.NET, can I allow a string starting with a number to be an ID?

Tags: asp.net, salesforce, sitefinity

I'm new to ASP.NET (building for Sitefinity) and working on a Salesforce form for a client. Some of their inputs looks like this:

```
<input  id="00N1600000Ernn3" maxlength="50" name="00N1600000Ernn3" size="20" type="text" />
```

So I created an input in asp like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="00N1600000Ernn3" MaxLength="50" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

When I compile I see this error coming from the designer file:

```
invalid token '00' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

If I switch the id to a start with a character it fixes the issue. My problem is Salesforce uses that as the name when submitted to update their database and analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Control ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to generate a property in the 'designer' file. Therefore, the ID must conform to the naming rules for identifiers. These rules specify that the identifier must start with a letter:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx

Comment: I was worried about and figured that. I've reached out the client to see if they could provide a custom name/id pair for the inputs instead of the one Salesforce generates.

Comment: Sitefinity has a Salesforce connector add on.

Answer (score 0):

Sitefinity does have a [Salesforce Connector](http://www.sitefinity.com/connector-for-salesforce) tool but the use of that module is tied to what license your client is using. One approach I've taken is instead of trying to match the ids of the Salesforce form, you can just paste the form html in a user control and then [register](http://docs.sitefinity.com/thunder-register-a-widget) that user control as a widget in Sitefinity using Thunder.

You may have to add in a button control to specify the postback url for the form:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit"  PostBackUrl="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" Text="Submit" />
```